# Multiple url path option error using graphql, aws lambda and serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using serverless framework to deploy a graphql nodejs package to lambda function.

My current `serverless.yml` file involves with a `POST` method for all communication and also another one for playground which looks like below.

```
functions:
  graphql:
    handler: handler.server
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: post
          cors: true
  playground:
    handler: handler.playground
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
          cors: true
```

And my handler.ts looks like this.

```
const { GraphQLServerLambda } = require("graphql-yoga");
const {documentSubmissionMutation} = require('./mutations/documentMutation');
const {signUpMutation, whatever} = require('./mutations/signUpMutation');

const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hello(name: String): String!
  },
  type Mutation {
    signUp(
      email: String!
      password: String!
    ): String

    sendDocuments(
      user_id: String!
      documents: String!
    ): String!
  }
`

const resolvers = {
  Query : {
    hello : whatever
  },
  Mutation: {
    sendDocuments: documentSubmissionMutation,
    signUp: signUpMutation,
  }
}

const lambda = new GraphQLServerLambda({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});

exports.server = lambda.graphqlHandler;
exports.playground = lambda.playgroundHandler;
```

What I would like to do now is have 3 different paths.
1 for secure and 1 for public and 1 for admin.
So basically the URL would be something like.
`localhost/public` `localhost/secre` `localhost/admin`
The secure path will use aws cognito pool to identify the API user api and and the other one would be open. The admin will use another aws cognito admin pool.

So first what I did was add it like this for a secure one.

```
const lambda = new GraphQLServerLambda({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: req => ({ ...req })
});

const lambdaSecure = new GraphQLServerLambda({
  typeDefsSecure,
  resolversSecure,
  context: req => ({ ...req })
});


exports.server = lambda.graphqlHandler;
exports.playground = lambda.playgroundHandler;

exports.serverSecure = lambdaSecure.graphqlHandler;
exports.playgroundSecure = lambdaSecure.playgroundHandler;
```

Then in my serverless.yml file tried to put it like this.

```
functions:
  graphql:
    handler: handler.server
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: post
          cors: true
  graphql:
    handler: handler.serverSecure
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: post
          cors: true

  playground:
    handler: handler.playground
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
          cors: true
  playground:
    handler: handler.playgroundSecure
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
          cors: true
```

It din't work and threw an error 
`duplicated mapping key in "/Users/nihit/Desktop/serverless/cvtre/serverless.yml" at line 50, column -135:
        graphql:`

I tried it in different ways but I am not really sure which one is the right way to get two different URL paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your `serverless.yml`. In particular in the functions specification. The combination of `path` and `method` as well as the function name must be unique for each function.

So, the `serverless.yml` should look like:

```
functions:
  graphqlServer:
    handler: handler.server
    events:
      - http:
          path: server/public
          method: post
          cors: true
  graphqlServerSecure:
    handler: handler.serverSecure
    events:
      - http:
          path: server/secure
          method: post
          cors: true

  playground:
    handler: handler.playground
    events:
      - http:
          path: playground/public
          method: get
          cors: true
  playgroundSecure:
    handler: handler.playgroundSecure
    events:
      - http:
          path: playground/secure
          method: get
          cors: true
```